# How can I remove commas while using regex.findall?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following string: 
`txt = "Balance: 47,124, age, ... Balance: 1,234 ..."`

(Ellipses denote other text).

I want to use regex to find the list of balances, i.e. 
`re.findall(r'Balance: (.*)', txt)`

But I want to return just 47124 and 1234 instead of 47,124 and 1,234.
Obviously I could replace the string afterwards, but that seems like iterating through the string twice, and thereby making this run twice as long.

I'd like to be able to output comma-less results *while* doing `re.findall`.

Comment: How big can the numbers get?

Comment: This is called overoptimization: `.replace(',', '')` will not cause much of an overhead. Anyway, you can't match disjoint strings of text within one match operation, so you will have to use a two step approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following regex pattern:

```
Balance: (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)
```

This will match only a comma-separated balance amount, and will not pick up on anything else.  Sample script:

```
txt = "Balance: 47,124, age, ... Balance: 1,234, age ... Balance: 123, age"
amounts = re.findall(r'Balance: (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)', txt)
amounts = [a.replace(',', '') for a in amounts]
print(amounts)

['47124', '1234', '123']
```

Here is how the regex pattern works:

```
\d{1,3}      match an initial 1 to 3 digits
(?:,\d{3})*  followed by `(,ddd)` zero or more times
```

So the pattern matches 1 to 999, and then allows these same values followed by one or more comma-separated thousands group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do the replacements as you process each match, which might be slightly more efficient than collecting all the matches and then doing the replacements:

```
txt = "Balance: 47,124, age, ... Balance: 1,234 ..."
balances = [bal.group(1).replace(',', '') for bal in re.finditer(r'Balance: ([\d,]+)', txt)]
print (balances)
```

Output:

```
['47124', '1234']
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agreed on the scanning, I'm thinking this can do the replacement as the strings are written to the array, rather than reprocessing each element in the output of `re.findall` to remove commas.